# Best way to consume multi-service consumption model

Tags: .net-core, apache-kafka

We have multiple background services(workers) having containerization, which will consume multiple Kafka topics, in order to maintain the chronological order and the integrity of data. What should be the best possible way for the consumption, should we use one consumer per topic or multiple topics per consumer.

Comment: Need more details. Kafka does not guarantee ordering across multiple topics, [as answered before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71796328/need-to-consume-multiple-kafka-topics)

Comment: We need to make sure that we get all the data if the order is not guaranteed. There can be 15-20 Kafka topics which can have 5-10 GB of data.

Comment: Okay, well, you'll need to programmatically determine what it means to "have all the data". Kafka doesn't know what you're planning on doing with the data and it doesn't really track the total size. So, for example, you could read all topics from the beginning and wait for all your consumer threads to reach the end of all the partitions, but this assumes there's no active producers or the consumers run faster than any producer so they actually will hit the eventual end of the topic. Ultimately, sounds to me like you should be writing the data to a database instead, then just query that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> consume multiple Kafka topics... maintain the chronological order

This simply isn't possible from a consumer client, regardless of the number of them you have. At least, not without actively sorting data as you're consuming it into an in-memory data structure (i.e. not parallelized or distributed)

You could write your data to a database *first* (using Kafka Connect, ideally, instead of your own .NET services), then write your apps to query the database, sorting by timestamp, instead of reading from Kafka directly.